# Can WiX reference a project with a period in the name?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, wix

WiX files can [reference other projects using `$(var.ProjectName.TargetPath)`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/votive_project_references.htm) syntax. However, I have a project with a period in the name (My.Project). How can I reference this? I have tried:

- `$(var.My.Project.TargetPath)`
- `$(var.My&#46;Project.TargetPath)`
- `$(var.My\.Project.TargetPath)`
- `$(var.{My.Project}.TargetPath)`
- `$(var.(My.Project).TargetPath)`
- `$(var.[My.Project].TargetPath)`
- `$(var.MyProject.TargetPath)`
- `$(var.My%2EProject.TargetPath)`

The build error I get is:

> Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.My.Project.TargetPath)'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sorry, I'm using WiX 3.5 and I can't reproduct your problem.  I created a sample solution with a class library called "Foo.Bar" and a Merge Module with a project reference for "Foo.Bar".

My  wixproj looks like:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Foo.Bar\Foo.Bar.csproj">
      <Name>Foo.Bar</Name>
      <Project>{0bd367ce-5072-4161-8447-ff4deed97bd4}</Project>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <DoNotHarvest>True</DoNotHarvest>
      <RefProjectOutputGroups>Binaries;Content;Satellites</RefProjectOutputGroups>
      <RefTargetDir>INSTALLLOCATION</RefTargetDir>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

My wxs looks like:

```
<Binary Id="TEST" SourceFile="$(var.Foo.Bar.TargetPath)"/>
```

Comment: Sorry to waste your time, it turns out it was my own fault.

Comment: It wasn't a waste of time.  I learned something new in that after I add the reference I could always manually update the Name element if I ever did have a problem like this in the future.

Answer (score 17):

The answer is yes, and the method is:

```
$(var.My.Project.TargetPath)
```

As it turns out, I'm a dope who forgets to add project references to his installer project.

Comment: Trying to upvote your comment for visibility. I had the same problem and the same cause.

Comment: oh man! i also wasted so much time to see i also did the same silly thing :)

Comment: Awesome. At least took me 2m to reach this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had issues with case sensitivity:

```
$(var.SomePrefix.MyProject.TargetPath)
```

did not work with the project named

```
"SomePrefix.Myproject"
```

It worked with a capital letter P in MyProject after renaming the project.